# Pandas pivot table with multiple columns and "yes" or "no" index

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I've been doing analysis of this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/yasserh/housing-prices-dataset
it contains columns ['mainroad', 'guestroom', 'basement', 'hotwaterheating', 'airconditioning', 'prefarea']
which all have values "yes" or "no" and I wanted to make pivot table out of it where table cells are mean price of houses, something like this:

| airconditioning | basement | guestroom | hotwaterheating | mainroad | prefarea |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| no 0.333333 | 0.666667 | 0.333333 | 0.333333 | 0.666667 | 0.333333 |
| yes 0.750000 | 0.250000 | 0.500000 | 0.750000 | 1.000000 | 1.000000 |

This is what I want to achive but by using pivot table:

```
df.groupby("mainroad")["price"].mean()
df.groupby("guestroom")["price"].mean()
df.groupby("basement")["price"].mean()
df.groupby("hotwaterheating")["price"].mean()
df.groupby("airconditioning")["price"].mean()
df.groupby("prefarea")["price"].mean()
```

This is what I tried and didn't work:
`pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['yes', 'no'], values=columns, aggfunc='mean')`

Also I would like to ask you in context of data analysis, is such approach of using pivot table and later on heatmap to display correlation between these columns and price a valid approach? How would you do that?

Comment: I think it's not possible to get this result with `pivot_table` without reshape your dataframe first.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you are closed to get what you expect:

```
cols = ['mainroad', 'guestroom', 'basement', 'hotwaterheating', 'airconditioning', 'prefarea']

out = pd.concat([df[[col, 'price']].groupby(col)['price'].mean()
                    for col in cols], keys=cols, axis=1)
print(out)

# Output

         mainroad     guestroom      basement  hotwaterheating  airconditioning      prefarea
no   3.398905e+06  4.544546e+06  4.509966e+06     4.728593e+06     4.191940e+06  4.425299e+06
yes  4.991777e+06  5.792897e+06  5.242615e+06     5.559960e+06     6.013221e+06  5.879046e+06
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) your data, then [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.mean.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
cols = ['mainroad', 'guestroom', 'basement', 'hotwaterheating', 'airconditioning', 'prefarea']

out = (df.melt(['price', 'area'], value_vars=cols)
         .groupby(['variable', 'value'])['price'].mean()
         .unstack(0)
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)[cols]
      )
```

Output:

```
         mainroad     guestroom      basement  hotwaterheating  airconditioning      prefarea
no   3.398905e+06  4.544546e+06  4.509966e+06     4.728593e+06     4.191940e+06  4.425299e+06
yes  4.991777e+06  5.792897e+06  5.242615e+06     5.559960e+06     6.013221e+06  5.879046e+06
```